# Adding a Set to HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need help adding a set to the hashmap: Each time i add a value to the set it will get the set of the key and add the new value to the set and put the set back.

The display method should just return the hashmap, which is completed already.

```
package HashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class Thesaurus {
    HashMap<String, Set<String>> words =new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();

    public void add(String x,String y)
    {
        words.put(x,words.get(x).add(y));
    }
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(words);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thesaurus tc = new Thesaurus();
        tc.add("large", "big");
        tc.add("large", "humoungus");
        tc.add("large", "bulky");
        tc.add("large", "broad");
        tc.add("large", "heavy");
        tc.add("smart", "astute");
        tc.add("smart", "clever");
        tc.add("smart", "clever");
        tc.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: should your display message `return` the map? That's easy. Or do you mean print it on the console?

Comment: I need help on the add method, I got the display method

Comment: was just goint to write, `add` will always throw a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void add(String x,String y) {
    Set<String> set = words.get(x);
    if (set == null) {
        words.put(x, set = new HashSet<String>());
    } 
    set.add(y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's guava SetMultimap for your thesaurus implementation:

```
public class Thesaurus {

    private SetMultimap<String, String> thesaurus = Multimaps.synchronizedSetMultimap(HashMultimap.create());  // word -> Set of its synonyms 
    
    
    public void addSynonym(String word, String synonym) {
        thesaurus.put(word, synonym);
    }
    
    public Set<String> getSynonyms(String word) {
        return thesaurus.get(word);
    }
    
    public void removeSynonym(String word, String synonymToRemove) {
        thesaurus.remove(word, synonymToRemove);
    }
}
```